# Kronymous 0.2.8 is working with Chrome 59.0.3071.9 (official Build) dev (at 64 bit)?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, vpn, chrome

According with this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kronymous/UkSZ3DOpdd4/Gx7K4HJLCgAJ),kronymous 0.2.8 seems to work with the the `Developer Channel 58.0.3029.31 (Official Build) dev (32-bit)`,so I have tried to check if it was true. I have installed `Chrome 59.0.3071.9 (official Build) dev (at 64 bit)` and also this [proxy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif),that I have configured like this :

[image]

and then,I opened a new tab on chrome where I wrote `chrome://apps` and I saw the Kronymous icon. When I clicked over this,I saw these messages :

> Loading NaCl module.
>
> Loaded.
>
> [notice] Tor v0.2.8.9 (git-61345e6ee264ca83) running on NaCl with Libevent 2.0.22-stable,OpenSSL 1.0.2e and Zlib 1.2.8.
>
> [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
>
> [notice] Read configuration file "/mnt/http/tor/conf".
>
> [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9999
>
> [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file
>
> /mnt/http/tor/geoip-files/geoip.
>
> [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /mnt/http/tor/geoip-files/geoip6.
>
> [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
>
> [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
>
> [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
>
> [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
>
> [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
>
> [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done

It seems there aren't errors,but when I clicked on `Are You Browsing Anonymously ?`,it said that I'm not running tor. So,it seems that it is configured correctly,but tor is not working ? Where is the mistake ? thanks.

Comment: N.B. this browsing won't be anonymous and will make non-Tor connections consistently.

Comment: I agree with @canonizingironize, Kronymous appears to provide very little when it comes to protecting your anonymity. Take a look at [Tor Browser's design document](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/) to see what is needed to provide anonymous browsing. And even the use of Tor Broswer, by itself, doesn't guarantee your anonymous.

Comment: why ? Why ? why ?

Comment: do you think that the use of a VPN is much better ?

Comment: this is cool and all but what if you can't add extentions much less tor to chrome chromebook? i say this because i am blocked from adding unaouthorized extentions and the tor site has no chrome version that i can find, if you know how to get past this it would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here :

http://techapple.net/2016/10/how-to-use-kronymous-to-access-tor-network-on-chrome-browser-google-chrome-os-chromebooks/

where it says :

Now, Once you have connected to Tor Network, simply open a new window , Select the “O” Omega  icon as shown in the image below , and select the “proxy” profile which we saved in the Step 1.

Comment: NB : the protocol of the proxy should be set to : SOCKS5